# Process unexpectedly exit when running android application on my phone from Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I installed Android studio and tested the default hello world app. It compiled without any issues. Then I connected my phone and tried to test the app on it. Gradle build failed with the following error-

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
> Please check if you installed the Windows Universal C Runtime.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

Process unexpectedly exit.

I haven't made any code changes or any config changes this just a fresh installation of android studio could anyone please help me with the same?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have gradle issue.
delete your current gradle folder from C drive
and download latest version from gradle.org

Comment: Hello I also found this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161096872 similar issue it seems something related to Windows update. But I updated my Windows and it ran fine for a while again after few runs it starts giving me the same issue

Answer (score 0):

A Dharmesh said you could delete gradle folder and also make sure you Clean your project  then rebuild. Then the last step would be File->Invalidate Caches/Restart -> click on Invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: Hello I also found this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161096872 similar issue it seems something related to Windows update. But I updated my Windows and it ran fine for a while again after few runs it starts giving me the same issue